# Returning Conditions on System of Linear INequalities

Tags: matlab, solver, inequalities

I am trying to solve linear inequalities for the conditions on the set of solutions. For example:

```
syms p C L D W
assume([p, C, W, D, L] >= 0)
eqn5 = p*C + L - D < 0;
eqn6 = p*C > 0;
solp2 = solve([eqn5, eqn6], [p, C, W, D, L], 'ReturnConditions', true);
Solp2p = solp2.p
Solp2C = solp2.C
Solp2W = solp2.W
Solp2D = solp2.D
Solp2L = solp2.L
Solp2cond = solp2.conditions
solp2par = solp2.parameters`
```

The conditions to solving this system of inequalities is clearly 0 < p*C < D- L. However it reports no solutions or conditions exist to satisfy this system of linear inequalities.

When using equalities these are the solutions I would receive using the solve function, however, when switching to inequalities it doesn't seem to work anymore. I also tried using vpasolve which didn't result in a solution either.

So far I have only found questions on Stack Overflow that give answers on how to find corner solutions or whether a solution exists for a system of linear inequalities.

I understand that the solution above implies an infinite number of solutions but this is easily captured using conditions as the solve function does for equalities. Does anyone know how to get these kind of solutions for a system of linear inequalities?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using mathematica and used the reduce function to find the solutions I am looking for.  Have not yet figured out how to do it in matlab.